# How to fix issue No route matches [DELETE] "/"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, devise

I use angular for front-end in my Ruby on Rails app

```
angular.module('rails_api')
  .controller('AuthController', ['$scope', '$location', '$http', 'Auth', function($scope, $location, $http, Auth){
    //auth
    var config = {
      headers: {
        'X-HTTP-Memthod-Override': 'POST'
      }
    }

    $scope.login = function () {
      Auth.login($scope.user, config).then(function(user) {
          console.log(user);
        }, function(error) {
      });

       $scope.$on('devise:login', function(event, currentUser){
         $location.path('/');
       });

       $scope.$on('devise:new-session', function(event, currentUser) {
            // user logged in by Auth.login({...})
        });
     }

     $scope.signup = function () {
      Auth.register($scope.user, config).then(function(registeredUser) {
            console.log(registeredUser); // => {id: 1, ect: '...'}
        }, function(error) {
            // Registration failed...
        });

        $scope.$on('devise:new-registration', function(event, user) {
            $location.path('/');
        });
      }

      $scope.logout = function () {
        var config = {
          headers: {
              'X-HTTP-Method-Override': 'DELETE'
          }
        };
        // Log in user...
        // ...
        Auth.logout(config).then(function(oldUser) {
          //console.log("oldUser");
             //alert(oldUser.name + "you're signed out now.");
        }, function(error) {
          console.log(error);
        });

        $scope.$on('devise:logout', function(event, oldCurrentUser) {
          $location.path('/');
        });
      }
  }]);
```

..

```
<li><a href="/auth/login"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
<li><a href="/auth/signup"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-registration-mark"></span> Sign UP</a></li>
<li><a href="" ng-controller="AuthController" ng-click="logout()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-registration-mark" target="_self"></span> Logout</a></li>
```

The login and signup function work all right, but logout not working, and my server show this error

```
Started DELETE "/users/sign_out.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-05-06 10:17:26 +0300

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [DELETE] "/users/sign_out.json"):
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
  web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
  web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:120:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
  /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:140:in `service'
  /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:96:in `run'
  /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/server.rb:296:in `block in start_thread'
```

It's my Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.3.0'

gem 'rails', '4.2.6'

gem 'pg', '~> 0.15'

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

gem 'rails_admin'
gem 'devise'

gem "bower-rails", "~> 0.10.0"
gem 'angular-rails-templates'
gem 'angular_rails_csrf'
gem 'rack-cors', :require => 'rack/cors'

gem 'faker'
gem 'pry'

gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'dropzonejs-rails'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'jasmine'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
end

gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production


source "https://rails-assets.org" do
  gem "rails-assets-angular-devise"
end
```

rake routes

```
                  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                      Controller#Action
                  images GET    /images(.:format)                images#index
                         POST   /images(.:format)                images#create
               new_image GET    /images/new(.:format)            images#new
              edit_image GET    /images/:id/edit(.:format)       images#edit
                   image GET    /images/:id(.:format)            images#show
                         PATCH  /images/:id(.:format)            images#update
                         PUT    /images/:id(.:format)            images#update
                         DELETE /images/:id(.:format)            images#destroy
           welcome_index GET    /welcome/index(.:format)         welcome#index
             rails_admin        /admin                           RailsAdmin::Engine
                   posts GET    /posts(.:format)                 posts#index
                         POST   /posts(.:format)                 posts#create
                new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)             posts#new
               edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)        posts#edit
                    post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)             posts#show
                         PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)             posts#update
                         PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)             posts#update
                         DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)             posts#destroy
            api_v1_posts GET    /api/v1/posts(.:format)          api/v1/posts#index
                         POST   /api/v1/posts(.:format)          api/v1/posts#create
         new_api_v1_post GET    /api/v1/posts/new(.:format)      api/v1/posts#new
        edit_api_v1_post GET    /api/v1/posts/:id/edit(.:format) api/v1/posts#edit
             api_v1_post GET    /api/v1/posts/:id(.:format)      api/v1/posts#show
                         PATCH  /api/v1/posts/:id(.:format)      api/v1/posts#update
                         PUT    /api/v1/posts/:id(.:format)      api/v1/posts#update
                         DELETE /api/v1/posts/:id(.:format)      api/v1/posts#destroy
            api_v1_users GET    /api/v1/users(.:format)          api/v1/users#index
                         POST   /api/v1/users(.:format)          api/v1/users#create
         new_api_v1_user GET    /api/v1/users/new(.:format)      api/v1/users#new
        edit_api_v1_user GET    /api/v1/users/:id/edit(.:format) api/v1/users#edit
             api_v1_user GET    /api/v1/users/:id(.:format)      api/v1/users#show
                         PATCH  /api/v1/users/:id(.:format)      api/v1/users#update
                         PUT    /api/v1/users/:id(.:format)      api/v1/users#update
                         DELETE /api/v1/users/:id(.:format)      api/v1/users#destroy
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)         devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)         devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session GET    /users/sign_out(.:format)        devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)        devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)    devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)   devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /users/password(.:format)        devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)        devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)          devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                 devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)         devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)            devise/registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /users(.:format)                 devise/registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                 devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                 devise/registrations#destroy
                    root GET    /                                welcome#index
                         GET    /*path(.:format)                 welcome#index

Routes for RailsAdmin::Engine:
  dashboard GET         /                                      rails_admin/main#dashboard
      index GET|POST    /:model_name(.:format)                 rails_admin/main#index
        new GET|POST    /:model_name/new(.:format)             rails_admin/main#new
     export GET|POST    /:model_name/export(.:format)          rails_admin/main#export
bulk_delete POST|DELETE /:model_name/bulk_delete(.:format)     rails_admin/main#bulk_delete
bulk_action POST        /:model_name/bulk_action(.:format)     rails_admin/main#bulk_action
       show GET         /:model_name/:id(.:format)             rails_admin/main#show
       edit GET|PUT     /:model_name/:id/edit(.:format)        rails_admin/main#edit
     delete GET|DELETE  /:model_name/:id/delete(.:format)      rails_admin/main#delete
show_in_app GET         /:model_name/:id/show_in_app(.:format) rails_admin/main#show_in_app
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do


      resources :images
      get 'welcome/index'

      mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'
      resources :posts

      namespace :api do
        namespace :v1 do
          resources :posts
          resources :users
        end
      end

      devise_for :users

      root to: 'welcome#index'
      get '*path' => "welcome#index"
    end
```

So I really don't understand what's the problem

Comment: Can you add `rake routes` output and related `routes.rb` file contents to your question?

Comment: I did. In devise config I use GET method

Comment: Yeap, that's the problem. You've setup devise to sign out on `GET`, where as you are sending `DELETE` requests.

Comment: I've added an answer with info where to look.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you must have specified that you want to use `GET` method to sign out in your `config/initializer/devise.rb` file.

Make sure you **don't have this line** in your initializer:

```
config.sign_out_via = :get
```

Comment: When I chenge devise config to DELETE method it's not working too.                   Started DELETE "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-05-06 10:49:17 +0300

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [DELETE] "/"):
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'

Comment: Don't change it to `:delete`, just comment that line. Also, in your comment `DELETE "/"` you are sending delete request to your root `/`, not `users/sign_out.json`.

Comment: I commented this line, but unsuccessfuly.                                            Started DELETE "/users/sign_out.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-05-06 10:54:55 +0300

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [DELETE] "/users/sign_out.json"):

Comment: Did you restart your rails app after changing?

Comment: Has your `rake routes` line for `destroy_user_session` changed from `GET` to `DELETE`?

Comment: No, this line with GET method

Comment: When I added  config.sign_out_via = :delete the logout work, but only when I reload page the session deleted

Comment: That's where the problem lies. You need to get it to `DELETE`, but it is not. Have you changed it somehow else? Try to run `spring stop` and then `rails s` again.

Comment: But you said it didn't?! You are sending ajax request, so you need to reload your page to get "not logged in" version of your page.

Comment: Uzbekjon, thanks. Maybe problem in Session Devise controller and I must override  some method for it(for example reload page)

Answer (score 0):

The routes file defines the routes in your case, to work only `HTML` requests, not for `JSON` request unless otherwise specified. But the request you are making: `Started DELETE "/users/sign_out.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-05-06 10:17:26 +0300` requests data in format `JSON` which your routes file doesn't understand.

Now, you have two options to get rid of this error:

1) Make sure that you request in `HTML` format, and not in `JSON` format through your code.

2) You can modify your routes so that they respond to `JSON` format as well. Following is how would you accomplish the task:

```
resources :users, :only => [:show], :defaults => { :format => 'json' }
```

Comment: Yes my javascript log send this line http://localhost:3000/users/sign_out.json 404 (Not Found), but POST method  with json data work

Answer (score 0):

In your routes.rb file explicitly define the routes with special methods like PUT and DELETE. E.g.

```
devise_scope :user  do
    delete '/sign_out' => 'sessions#destroy',  :defaults => { :format => 'json' }
    put '/signup' => 'registrations#update',  :defaults => { :format => 'json' }
end
```

Although these routes are already created by "devise_for :users" and worked on postman, without explicitly creating them my RSPec tests failed.